# Exo. 22:24 - "I will kill you with the sword"

Tags: exodus

What punishment is being described in [Exo. 22:24](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Exo&c=22&v=24&t=KJV#s=t_conc_72024)?

> And my wrath shall wax hot, and I will kill you with the sword; and your wives shall be widows, and your children fatherless. (KJV)

- What exactly is the punishment described by "with the sword" (בֶּחָרֶב)?
- Who will deliver the punishment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correctly understand the passage, one must understand the context, Ex. 22:22-24,

> **Ye shall not afflict any widow, or fatherless child.
>   23 If thou afflict them in any wise, and they cry at all unto me, I
>   will surely hear their cry;
>   24 And my wrath shall wax hot, and I will kill you with the sword; and
>   your wives shall be widows, and your children fatherless.**

The Lord is the 'husband' to the widows, and the Father to the fatherless children; therefore He directly intervenes with those who would harm or exploit those who are in His care and cry out to Him. Psalm 68:5,

> **A father of the fatherless, and a judge of the widows, is God in his
>   holy habitation.**

Rashi's Commentary on this passage makes this interesting remark,([from here](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9883#showrashi=true))

> *If you oppress him: This is an elliptical verse. It threatens
>   [punishment], but does not delineate his punishment. [This is] similar
>   to “Therefore, whoever kills Cain…!” (Gen. 4:15). It threatens, but
>   does not delineate his punishment. Here too, “If you oppress him” is
>   an expression of a threat: If you oppress him [the orphan], you will
>   ultimately receive what is coming to you. Why? “For if he cries out to
>   Me, etc.”*

In the next verse(23) he says,

> *and your wives will be widows: From the implication of what is
>   said-“and I will slay you” -do I not know that your wives will be
>   widows and your children orphans? Rather, this is another curse,
>   namely that the wives will be bound in living widowhood -there will be
>   no witnesses to their husbands’ deaths, and [thus] they will be
>   forbidden to remarry. The children will be orphans because the court
>   will not allow them to have their fathers’ property, since they do not
>   know whether they died or were captured. -[From Mechilta, B.M. 38b]*

It does not state "which sword" or "who's sword" will slay you; but know for a certainty this shall happen to you, because of your oppression of the widows and orphans. This means at any time, just when you 'think' you have gotten away with it', judgment will come, because they cried out to Me.